# Cannot use Ubuntu using Intel HD drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, intel-graphics, asus, gpu-driver

I have an Asus N552VW-FY136T and I seem to be unable to start Ubuntu 17.10 using my Intel HD integrated graphic card, it only works with the dedicated GTX 960M.
The first boot works fine after the installation, boots up and runs using the Intel HD.
Then, it seems to install some proprietary driver automatically. This way at the next boot it gets stuck at the purple screen.
Also, in the "Additional Drivers" window it appears to be that   while the nVidia GPU is correctly recognized, the Intel is listed as "Unknown: Unknown"
I have tried bumblebee and to switch to the Intel using the prime select, but this gets me to either a black screen or gets the fan to rotate at max speed after 10s that Ubuntu booted up.

Is there anything I can do? The 960m uses up a lot of battery and I don't need a powerful gpu in Ubuntu.. it's not ideal to have 1 and a half hour of battery life when in university..

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

ok, basically I managed to disable effectively the nVidia card.

basically, I have blacklisted the nvidia modules, here's how I did it:

open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install bbswitch-dkms
```

then

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

inside the file, type:

```
# Blacklist the alternative nvidia module 
blacklist nouveau
# Blacklist the original nvidia module 
blacklist nvidia
```

press *ctrl* and *x* to close, press '*y*' to save the changes.

Now,

```
sudo nano /etc/modules
```

add this line:

```
bbswitch load_state=0
```

ctrl x to save, 'y' to confirm.

then update the ramdisk

```
 sudo update-initramfs -u
```

finally, reboot. It should boot up just fine.